# AVCapturesession not working for real product barcodes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode-scanner, avcapturesession

The barcode scanner works on a Mac screen, but not on real products like maggi etc.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _highlightView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _highlightView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    _highlightView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    _highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    [self.view addSubview:_highlightView];

    _label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _label.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40);
    _label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15 alpha:0.65];
    _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _label.text = @"(none)";
    [self.view addSubview:_label];

    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;

    _input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
    if (_input) {
        [_session addInput:_input];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    _output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_session addOutput:_output];

    _output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

    _prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    _prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];

    [_session startRunning];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_highlightView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_label];
}
```

Is there a problem? I have used most the code from avcapturesession , AVmetadataoutput etc. But it reads only on lcd screens.

Answer (score 1):

create your AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate like

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
NSString *detectionString = nil;
NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                          AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                          AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];
for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
    for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
        if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
        {
            barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
            highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;
            detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];

            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: yes. thanks David. But been done this before. Only working in display screen.

Answer (score 0):

check your _output.metadataObjectTypes, you have to add all type of barcode in that. for example(EAN8,EAN13.....e.t.c)

Comment: Thanks Sagar, but its also been tried. But it read from lcd screen all the formats, but not in real world.

Comment: _output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[_session addOutput:_output];

_output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];//here you add all types of barcode in an array

Comment: did the same sagar.

Comment: This is only working when i scan on lcd screen. Is there any camera related issue.